# Grails Date variable will not set the time

Tags: date, grails, grails-orm, gsp

I make a simple domain class

```
class Meetings {

    Date when
    String where
}
```

Then I run 'generate-all' on Meetings. I then start the app 'RunApp'.
In the app I'm able to to choose the month, day, and year for the when variable, however I can't choose the time as in hours:minutes (example 7:30). I wouldn't expect to be able to do this, but if I save the date it formats it as month, day, year, and then -00:00:00. How do I set the time using the date variable? or is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the datepicker tag in grails, it is pretty straight forward. 
In the views folder under a domain class folder there is `_form.gsp`. Inside `_form.gsp` is a date picker tag.

```
<g:datePicker name="dateTimeVariableName" value="${dateTimeValue}"
          default="${new Date().clearTime()}" precision="minute"/>
```

The keyword here is **precision**.

You should check the [documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.2.4/ref/Tags/datePicker.html). Its always a good idea. Hope this helps.

Comment: I've seen this, but I don't think this is what I'm looking for. I was looking for a domain class way, so I don't have to fight everything I'm trying to do.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use this. It makes you able to select the time and date like I want, but I can't get it to save to the database through gorm.

Comment: @College Now App Group Well, the params.dateTimeVariable would hold the whole value. However, you can access the values individually. Just print out the parameters and you know what I mean. ` new Date(params.dateTimeVariable)` should do the trick. You can use clearTime to clear the time values if needed.

Comment: Thanks this worked +1 . I just didn't know where it was located in _form.gsp I was using the create or show.gsp. Now I just need to figure out how to format it when it displays in show.